# C#: Can a self signed certificate be removed programmatically?

Tags: c#, ssl, iis

I followed this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632757/how-to-remove-certificate-from-store-cleanly) to remove the certificate from the store. But, in IIS I can still see the certificate. Can this thing be done programmatically?

[image]

Comment: sure - what research have you done?

Comment: @ Daniel, I followed that "stackoverflow post".....Through that, I was able to uninstall the certificate from Trusted Root Certification Authorities.......Also, the certificate is self signed(which I am creating on the fly for my wcf service)

Comment: http://jexusmanager.com check its source and you can do the same.